# PHP JQuery CheckBox

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have the following snippet.

```
    var myData = {
    video: $("input[name='video[]']:checked").serialize(),
    sinopse: $("#sinopse").val(),
    dia: $("#dia").val(),
    quem: $("#quem").val()
};

jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
                $("#responds").append(response);
                $(".video").val(''); //empty text field on successful
                $("#sinopse").val('');
                $("#dia").val('');
                $("#quem").val('');
                $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
                $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image

            },
```

all variables except "video" are getting saved in database. What can be wrong here? (maybe the problem is with jquery)

Comment: There's an extra comma at the end of your code, and you're missing a `);` as well. (Unless there's more code that should come afterwards?)

Answer (score 1):

refer this link:-  [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

You can get selected checkboxes values by

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").serialize();
```